# How can I echo JS redirection?

Tags: javascript, php

I want to echo a javascript mobile device redirection to the mobile site.
But I have to give an 'id' with the redirect link. This is my code as of now:

```
<?
  if (screen.width <= 800) {
    window.location("mplayer.php?id=" . $_GET['id'] . "");
  }
?>
```

But it gives me this error(s)

> Notice: Use of undefined constant screen - assumed 'screen' in /home/jterweele/public_html/pack-simulator/16/player.php on line 16
>
> Notice: Use of undefined constant width - assumed 'width' in /home/jterweele/public_html/pack-simulator/16/player.php on line 16
>
> Notice: Use of undefined constant window - assumed 'window' in /home/jterweele/public_html/pack-simulator/16/player.php on line 17
>
> Fatal error: Call to undefined function location() in /home/jterweele/public_html/pack-simulator/16/player.php on line 17

Hope someone can help me.
Thanks!

Comment: You are attempting to run javascript code as php code. You can put your php tags just around this: `$_GET['id']` like `<?= $_GET['id'] ?>`

Comment: thats js not php so you need to include the apporate tags `<script>` etc

Comment: JS and PHP are ***two different animals***.

Comment: wait was he trying to check for screen width in php?

Comment: If so, my answer is junk

Comment: *"wait was he trying to check for screen width in php?"* - @ChrisTrudeau Yep.

Comment: I need to take a nap or do something else for awhile, things are starting to blend together

Comment: *buona notte* @ChrisTrudeau ;-)

Comment: @datasage thanks!! It works!

Comment: @user5286072 did I write this for nothing? http://stackoverflow.com/a/34476103/1415724 where I specifically outlined the problems and provided you with a solution.

Answer (score 1):

JS and PHP are two different animals and they do not mix together the way you are using those presently, which explains the syntax errors you are getting, because you are declaring what PHP thinks are constants.

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.constant.php

What you need to do is to seperate those.

First, the JS/HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
   <title></title>
</head>

<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    <!--
    if (screen.width <= 800) {
       window.location = "redirection_page.php?set=true";
    }

    else {
       document.write ("Show them a message, or do something else.");
    }
    //-->
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Then the PHP: (redirection_page.php)

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['set']) && $_GET['set'] == true ){

header("Location: http://www.example.com/");

exit;

}
```

---

So, in your case that would read something like this:

**N.B.:** (You will need to do some modifications as to what the GET array will be).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
   <title></title>
</head>

<body>

<?php 

$_GET['id'] = 2;

?>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    <!--
    if (screen.width <= 800) {
       window.location = "mplayer.php?id=<?php echo $_GET['id'] ?>";
    }

    else {

       document.write ("Show them a message, or do something else.");

    }

    //-->
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

PHP: (mplayer.php)

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id'] == 2 ){

   echo $id = $_GET['id'];

}
```

---

Also make sure that you are not outputting before header (this means no HTML above the PHP, a space before the `<?php` tag, a cookie, etc. If this doesn't work for you, then your system may not be set to catch/display errors/notices/warnings, so enable error reporting.

If you do see a headers sent notice, read the following on Stack:

- [How to fix "Headers already sent" error in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php)

---

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Displaying errors should only be done in staging, and never production.